# solving non-linear differential equations by series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

1. > $xy''=yy'$ .

Solve the differential equation using series solution. I think no polynomial solution for $y$ as a function of $x$ exists.

Comment: Explore whether a polynomial solution $y(x)$ is possible, by a degree argument.  For example, any constant function is a solution.

Comment: Even if there were no polynomial solutions, power series solutions may exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

This belongs to an ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0324.pdf.

Let $u=\dfrac{xy'}{y}$ ,

Then $y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-u+y+1$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u=y+1$

$\dfrac{d(yu)}{dy}=y+1$

$yu=\int(y+1)~dy$

$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^2}{2}+y+c_1$

$\dfrac{dy}{y^2+2y+C_1}=\dfrac{dx}{2x}$